# Will copy constructor be run for this code?

Tags: c++, optimization, reference, copy-constructor, language-lawyer

Given the following C++ code:

```
struct foo {
  // Some definition with copy constructor.
};

const foo &getData();

const foo &alt1(getData());
const foo &alt2 = getData();
```

Will a reasonable compiler produce different code for `alt1` and `alt2`?  In other words, will `alt1` cause the copy constructor to be run, or is the compiler allowed to optimize that away and assign the reference directly?

Comment: This question would make more sense if `alt1` and `alt2` were not references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both cases, you initialize a *reference* (not an object), so no copy-constructor will be run.

Answer (score 2):

```
const foo &alt1(getData());
const foo &alt2 = getData();
```

These two are exactly the same.  There are no copies here, with or without optimization.

Answer (score 2):

No. In your code,`alt1` and `alt2` are references to the object returned from `getData()`. So no object will be created to begin with, so there is no question of invocation of copy-constructor either.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete these answer, if the signature of getData() was "foo getData();" then you would need a copy constructor to exits and be accessible even if most compiler don't generate any call to it.